# How to insert values into an SQL table using triggers and if conditions?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, where-clause, sql-insert

Essentially I am trying to create a 'Retired' SQL table which will get its values from an already existing 'Staff' SQL table.

If the staff has more than 5 YearsOfService, then he/she will be added to the retired table.

I am sharing the code that I have tried.

```
CREATE TABLE Retired(
   StaffID INT
);

DELIMITER #
CREATE TRIGGER RetiredTrigger after insert on Staff 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
INSERT INTO ALUMNI(StaffID) VALUES(new.StaffID);
IF Staff.YearsOfService > 5
END #
```

The result should ideally be a table(i.e. Retired Table) that should have StaffID's of only those teachers who have YearsOfService greater than 5.

I hope I was able to articulate my doubts clearly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When/How is this `YearsOfService` updated? It would be better to store a startdate for a staff-member, than a field which contains YearsOfService ...

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Retired(
   StaffID INT
);

DELIMITER #
CREATE TRIGGER RetiredTrigger after insert on Staff 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
IF (NEW.YearsOfService > 5) THEN
INSERT INTO Retired(StaffID) VALUES(new.StaffID);
END IF;
END #
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Mistakes made in original code: Table Retired created but values inserted into another Table called ALUMNI. There was no END IF for IF statement. Also NEW variable is not used for comparing YearsOfService.

Comment: you can add that to the answer itself )